# Как создать генерацию слов в приложении под Android?

Tags: java, android

Хочу создать игру для Android что-то типа Крокодила или Шляпы, где будут генерироваться слова. Подскажите, как можно организовать хранение этих слов и вообще можно ли их откуда-то взять?

Comment: Поищи какое-то API. Я думаю, что что-то подобное найдется.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, словарь вы можете взять отсюда http://speakrus.ru/dict/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

я бы создал массив типа String для хранения всех слов, но придется вручную забивать слова, или же создать обычный текстовик со списком нужных слов и через FileReader записать все слова текстовика в массив, после для генерации рандомных (или чего там вам надо) слов использовать обычный math.random(). Он будет вытаскивать случайные слова из массива